# Does privacy equal security?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has the IT Security S.E. evolved into a S.E. for information security?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/741/has-the-it-security-s-e-evolved-into-a-s-e-for-information-security)

On a lot of security websites, including security.stackexchange.com, I find a lot of stuff regarding privacy.

For example, the question [Is Google spying on all of us?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/is-google-spying-on-all-of-us). It is not really about security, rather about privacy.

How is privacy related to security?

Comment: Also see [Where should I ask questions specifically about privacy and anonymity?](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/810/33)

Comment: Privacy is not the same as security, but in many regards security is required to protect privacy.